# Does LD_INCLUDE_PATH actually do anything?

Tags: c, gcc, path

The GCC manual [documents](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Environment-Variables.html) the use of the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable to specify additional directories to be searched for include files when preprocessing C programs. However, I've also not infrequently encountered [references](http://www.google.com/search?q=LD_INCLUDE_PATH) to a mysterious supposed `LD_INCLUDE_PATH` environment variable, which is presumed to operate similarly.

I suspect that no such environment variable is actually supported by the GNU toolchain, at least; after all, why would the linker need an include path? My guess is that `LD_INCLUDE_PATH` is a conflation between `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but since googling has not provided a definitive answer, I pose the question here so as to help put the matter to rest for anyone searching for information about this in the future. So: is `LD_INCLUDE_PATH` fictitious, or not?

Comment: Includes have nothing to do with linking, much less the dynamic linker. Since `LD_*` variables are for the dynamic linker, this seems bogus...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct: there's no such thing as `LD_INCLUDE_PATH`, and I bet you're right, it's an "invention" by confused people. The Google references I found to it were clearly all people surprised that it didn't work, and unclear about what it was supposed to do.